# Error Facing while updating price of all products in magento

Tags: price

I am facing an error while updating prices of all product eg. i have 2000 products it will update the price of some of the product and rest of it will not update

i use to follow this link to update the price 
http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/updating-product-prices-in-magento-in-easier-faster-way/

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Error is it shows there is no product code with this sku code but actually it exist

Comment: Try removing header row, SKU and price from CSV. Also first check with one or two entries in CSV file. If it's working, then go with all records.

Comment: but it updates the price of some of products.

Comment: Still it shows the same error after removing the sku and price field

Comment: Yes i am very much sure that the product code is there in csv file as well as in my magento website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that the SKU exists, you can update your code like below and then check.

```
function _updatePrices($data){

    $connection     = _getConnection('core_write');

    $sku            = trim($data[0]);

    $newPrice       = $data[1];

    $productId      = _getIdFromSku($sku);

    $attributeId    = _getAttributeId();

 

    $sql = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity_decimal') . " cped

                SET  cped.value = ?

            WHERE  cped.attribute_id = ?

            AND cped.entity_id = ?";

    $connection->query($sql, array($newPrice, $attributeId, $productId));
```

}

It happens sometimes that there is a blank space in SKU value in CSV.

Comment: Still its not working i tried your solution still it shows that the sku code is not  exist but actually its there in csv file and  it also shows in magento admin panel -> cataloge-> product

Comment: Its working now the same issue as you said it takes the blank space is there so thanks you very much for your quick response

Comment: If the solution worked for you then please accept the answer so it can be helpful to others facing the same issue.

Comment: One more thing i need to ask is how can i remove the extra space with sku code in cataloge-> product-> sku.

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer to your second question.

```
<?php

$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';

require_once $mageFilename;

Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

umask(0);

Mage::app('admin');

Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

set_time_limit(0);

ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');

    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection ();
    foreach($collection as $product){ $sku = trim($product->getSku());
    $product->setSku($sku)->save();
    }
```

Create a new file in your Magento root folder and put this code in it. Then run file.

Comment: In the same file do i need to edit ?

Comment: Please check updated answer

Comment: So that will remove the all white space around the sku code right ?